# Symfony 3 - Form not adding "has-error" class when error occured in VichImageType and custom constraint

Tags: php, symfony, vichuploaderbundle, symfony2-easyadmin

**Problem view:**

[image: Error]

**Problem code:**

[image]

**Form:**

```
    $builder->add('title', Type\TextType::class, [
        'label_attr' => ['class' => 'required label-required'],
    ]);
    $builder->add('isPublished');
    $builder->add('imageFile', VichImageType::class, [
        'label_attr'     => ['class' => 'required label-required'],
        'allow_delete'   => false,
    ]);
    $builder->add('alt', Type\TextType::class, [
        'label_attr' => ['class' => 'required label-required'],
    ]);
```

**Question:**

Could anyone tell me, why `has-error` is not added to 3rd form field? To generate errors, `title` field is using `@Assert\NotBlank()` and "Image file" is using my custom constraint:

**FileNotEmpty** class:

```
<?php

namespace Notimeo\CoreBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 * @Target("CLASS")
 */
class FileNotEmpty extends Constraint
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $message = 'This field cannot be empty.';

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public $fields = [];

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return get_class($this).'Validator';
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTargets()
    {
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }
}
```

**FileNotEmptyValidator** class:

```
<?php

namespace Notimeo\CoreBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

/**
 * Class FileNotEmptyValidator
 *
 * @package Notimeo\CoreBundle
 */
class FileNotEmptyValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    /**
     * @param mixed      $protocol
     * @param Constraint $constraint
     */
    public function validate($protocol, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        /* @var $constraint FileNotEmpty */
        foreach($constraint->fields as $field) {
            $method1 = 'get'.ucfirst($field);
            $method2 = $method1.'File';

            $value1 = call_user_func([$protocol, $method1]);
            $value2 = call_user_func([$protocol, $method2]);

            if(empty($value1) && empty($value2)) {
                $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                    ->atPath($field.'File')
                    ->addViolation();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using newest *Symfony 3* and *EasyAdminBundle* to generate this form. What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

We recently made some changes related to this. See: https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/commit/3405a7a1029762365a08d38d59765197836c9fcb

Can you please check if you are using a version of the bundle that includes those changes? Thanks!

Comment: I'm using `dev-master` version. Updated today. Still the same.